# Puppeteer Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, puppeteer

I am trying to take a screenshot of the launched page using puppeteer but it threw error

> TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

This is my code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();
var Xvfb = require('xvfb');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

StealthPlugin.onBrowser = () => { };
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin);

// Required for virtual display in linux environment
var xvfb = new Xvfb({
    displayNum: 99,
    reuse: true,
    silent: true,
    xvfb_args: ['-dpi', 72, "-screen", "0", '1920x1080x24'],
});
xvfb.start((err) => { if (err) console.error(err) })

puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: 'bot',
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--proxy-server="direct://"',
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--start-fullscreen',
        '--display=' + xvfb._display
    ]
}).then(async browser => {
    console.log('Starting bot ...');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('server is listening at port 3000')
    })

    app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
        res.send('Test')
    })

    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
    await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com', { timeout: 0, waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    // await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
});
```

It's working if I run in my windows localhost device but throwing error above when I run in ubuntu server. It wasn't able to listen to the port that I set too. It seem to be having error at the line `await browser.newPage();`

I know this issue has been posted many times but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your issue is website is not properly load you can try this code

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')();
var Xvfb = require('xvfb');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

StealthPlugin.onBrowser = () => { };
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin);

// Required for virtual display in linux environment
var xvfb = new Xvfb({
    displayNum: 99,
    reuse: true,
    silent: true,
    xvfb_args: ['-dpi', 72, "-screen", "0", '1920x1080x24'],
});
xvfb.start((err) => { if (err) console.error(err) })

puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    userDataDir: 'bot',
    args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--proxy-server="direct://"',
        '--proxy-bypass-list=*',
        '--start-fullscreen',
        '--display=' + xvfb._display
    ]
}).then(async browser => {
    console.log('Starting bot ...');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log('server is listening at port 3000')
    })

    app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
        res.send('Test')
    })

    await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com', { waitUntil: 'load' });
    // await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
    await page.waitForNavigation();
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply. I'm not quite sure why it doesn't load the browser but I changed the `headless` to `true` then it is running now.

Comment: `await page.waitForNavigation()` should be called before you move the navigation vía `goto` or even doing a `page.click()` or form `submit()`.